# how to solve orchardcms remove html tags for example a tag?

Tags: orchardcms

I want insert

```html
 <a href=""></a>
```

tag in content

I insert this tag in html source code and click ok and publish . but orchardcms remove those tag.
how to solve this???
Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The tag is kept, even if its empty. What exactly are you trying to do, inserting empty tags?

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roymy <a> tag is top of all elements

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question. I still have no idea how to help you. I'll have to recommend closing this question unless you can elaborate. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Bertrand . my problem is :  i want insert <a> tag (link) at first line of my html and above my paragraph . but after publish , orchard cms remove this <a> tag !!! for example :  `<a href="https://stachoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a><p>test paragraph</p>`

Comment: Put it in a p tag where it will be valid?